# Python - Counting Prime Factors

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a Python newbie so I apologize if the answer is obvious and I'm oblivious to something simple.

I'm trying to count the number of factors of a prime number so that it will print: "It has X factors," but I'm running against a brick wall - I'm not sure how or the best way to count the number of previously generated list.

I'm also confused on part of my Prime Number determination. It generally works well, but when I input numbers like 15, 25, 35, etc. it all comes back as saying the number is prime when they aren't. It isn't all multiples of 5 either.

All help is appreciated!

My code:

```
# Main Program

def main():
 choice = "y"
 while choice.lower() == "y":
      print ("Prime Number Checker")
      print ()
      is_prime()
      print()
      choice = input("Try Again (y/n)?: ")
 choice = "n"
 while choice.lower() == "n":
      break

# Prime number determination and Output

def is_prime():
      num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 5,000: "))
      if num > 1:
           for i in range (2, num):
                if (num % i) != 0:
                          print()
                          print ("The factors of your number are:")
                          factors (num)
                          print (num, "is a Prime Number")
                          break
                elif (num % i) == 0:
                          print ()
                          print ("The factors of your number are:")
                          factors (num)
                          print (num, "is NOT a Prime Number")
                          numfacs (num)
                          break
      else:
           print ()
           print ("Number not in range.")
           print ()

# Factor Determination and Output

def factors(num):
 for i in range (1, num+1):
      if (num % i == 0):
           print (i)

# Number of Facotors and Output

def numfacs(num):
 for i in range (1, num+1):
      if (num % i == 0):
           list = []
           print ("Length: ", len(list))
           break

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is happening because, if the number you evaluate (e.g 15) is not dividable by the first element of the for loop (number 2 in this case), then it will be evaluated as prime number.
To fix this, you can add flag marking if a number is prime while the loop is running. If it stops being prime (if you can divide it by another number) then the flag changes to False.

Bellow is a working example of what I've said. If you don't understand something please say so.

```
# Main Program

def main():
 choice = "y"
 while choice.lower() == "y":
      print ("Prime Number Checker")
      print ()
      is_prime()
      print()
      choice = input("Try Again (y/n)?: ")
 choice = "n"
 while choice.lower() == "n":
      break

# Prime number determination and Output

def is_prime():
    flag=False
    num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 5,000: "))
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2, num):
            if (num % i) != 0:
                flag=True
            elif (num % i) == 0:
                flag=False
                print ()
                print ("The factors of your number are:")
                factors (num)
                print (num, "is NOT a Prime Number")
                numfacs (num)
                break
        if flag == True :
            print(num,i,num % i)
            print()
            print ("The factors of your number are:")
            factors (num)
            print (num, "is a Prime Number")
    else:
        print ()
        print ("Number not in range.")
        print ()

# Factor Determination and Output

def factors(num):
 for i in range (1, num+1):
      if (num % i == 0):
           print (i)

# Number of Facotors and Output

def numfacs(num):
 for i in range (1, num+1):
      if (num % i == 0):
           list = []
           print ("Length: ", len(list))
           break

main()
```

**NOTE:** This line will not work in Python versions bellow 3.0:

```
choice = input("Try Again (y/n)?: ")
```

Instead use this:

```
choice = str(raw_input("Try Again (y/n)?: "))
```

Comment: No problem :) If you need anything more please say so. If this answer solved your problems please mark it as accepted! ;)